# Radio Button As image is not working properly in Internet Explorer Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, radio-button, microsoft-edge

In IE Edge  radio button get checked/unchecked when in click on label text(Male/female) but not when I click on image adjacent to male/female. Where as in other browser radio button get checked/unchecked when  i click on image as well as text(Male/Female).

Html:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
<div class="pull-left formQuestions"><p>Which gender do you identify with?</p></div>
<div class="pull-left individualAnswer">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left optionOne">
<input type="radio" name="gender"  id="male" class="input-hidden" ng-model="genderSelect" ng-value = "'male'" ng-change = "genderSelection(genderSelect)" required/>
<label for="male" class="radioLabel">
 <img class="radioPic" ng-src={{imgPathMale}} /> Male 
</label>
</div>
<div class="pull-left">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="input-hidden" ng-model="genderSelect" ng-value = "'female'" ng-change = "genderSelection(genderSelect)" required/>
<label for="female" class="radioLabel"> <img class="radioPic" ng-src={{imgPathFemale}} />Female                           
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-hidden{
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

Js:

```
$scope.genderSelection = function(gender){

  if(gender == 'male'){
  $scope.imgPathMale = "assets/images/form_radio_selected.png";
  $scope.imgPathFemale = "assets/images/form_radio_unselected.png";
  }
  else{
  $scope.imgPathFemale = "assets/images/form_radio_selected.png";
  $scope.imgPathMale = "assets/images/form_radio_unselected.png";   
  }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label{
   display:inline-block;
}
label img{
 pointer-events: none;
 -moz-user-select: -moz-none; // to remove blue color highlight in which we 
   //get on clicking image in firefox.
}
```